# Using DataSnap and Advantage Database Server

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server, datasnap

I have tried to use DataSnap on Advantage Database but I cannot update my data. I use TAdsQuery on datasnap server and return the query to client and link it with TDataSetProvider.
I traced into and saw Delphi applies updates using TSQLConnection not my TAdsConnection I have in server side.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a white paper for Advantage (Sybase) to show how Advantage Database Server and Delphi's DataSnap work just fine. I'm not sure what/where your problem is exactly.

Check out http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinD8.htm for the DataSnap Server and http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinD9.htm for the client.

The DataSnap client uses a TSQLConnection to talk to the DataSnap Server. The DataSnap Server uses a TAdsConnection to talk to the Advantage Database Server. The client never has any "knowledge" about the actual database; that's what the server is for.

Groetjes, Bob Swart

Comment: +1. Nice, Dr. Bob. I'd missed those articles. Drat! Have to delete my answer now. <g>